# Orbeon - Does the persistence API not support a POST to create form data?

Tags: orbeon

The [persistence API documentation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-CRUD) says:

> When using GET, PUT and DELETE to deal with resources, the body of HTTP requests just contains the resource to handle.

This seems to indicate that POST is not a supported operation. The documentation only mentions GET, PUT and DELETE.

I have read elsewhere (I can't remember where) that it is possible to POST to:

`http://[SERVER]/orbeon/fr/[APP_NAME]/[FORM_NAME]/new`

I have tested this and it works, but this is not using the REST API. It returns a page intended for a user to begin editing the form data. This isn't really what I'm looking for. I would have expected to be able to do a POST to

`http://[SERVER]/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/[APP_NAME]/[FORM_NAME]/data/`

And that the location of the newly created form data (including its document ID) would be returned in the `Location` header of the response. But doing a POST returns a 500 error. The stack trace seems to indicate a validation exception of some kind. Is this not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, the persistence API doesn't support POST, and but you [can POST to the /new page](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Configuration-properties#initial-instance-posted-to-the-new-form-page), which are two very different things.

So, if you want to call the persistence API directly, and want to create a new document, you need to "pick" a document id. You could do this by using the same code Form Runner calls: `secure:randomHexId()`, implemented in [`SecureUtils.scala`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/util/SecureUtils.scala).

Comment: Do you mean that I can do a PUT to `http://[SERVER]/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/[APP_NAME]/[FORM_NAME]/data/[MY_GENERATED_DOCUMENT_ID]/data.xml`? I tried this but I just get 400 - Bad Request.

Comment: I am using the header `Content-Type: application/xml`. I also tried using the URL parameter `valid=false`. The content I'm using is copied directly from a GET for the same form. I just changed the last number in the document ID from a `4` to a `5`.

Comment: The document ID I used should be a valid hex ID. If I change the document ID back to the existing one I used for the GET, it works fine and returns 201 - Created.

Comment: I figured out that the reason I was getting a 400 when using a new ID is that I was not including the Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version header. This header is not required for updating an existing ID since the version is already stored in the database. The requirement for this header is not mentioned in the [Persistence API documentation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api). This doc only mentions that the header is passed when publishing.

Comment: Thanks, @avernet for updating the doc: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-CRUD